# AWS ALB->Lambda 502

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've looked all over but haven't found much about this.  The docs/debugging on ALB seem pretty poor...

I'm getting 502s from ALB for reasons I cannot discern.  I've got an ALB with a Lambda target.  My Lambda sends this to the ALB:

> {\n  statusCode: 200,\n  body: 'Root...',\n  multiValueHeaders: {\n
> 'x-powered-by': [ 'Express' ],\n    'access-control-allow-origin': [
> '*' ],\n    'content-type': [ 'text/html; charset=utf-8' ],\n
> 'content-length': [ '7' ],\n    etag: [
> 'W/"7-bEyWHAj7Nx3j68RN5+dEhPIpvp0"' ]\n  },\n  isBase64Encoded:
> false,\n  statusDescription: '200 OK'\n}`

I get the following in the Cloudwatch logs:

> h2 2021-01-10T18:48:47.956319Z app/api-dev/955d2b8cbf36b4d0
> 73.231.54.75:32892 - 0.005 0.029 0.000 502 - 19 594 "GET https://api.dev.co:443/docs HTTP/2.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
> Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2
> arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:025080367422:targetgroup/api-dev/106c350fe23bff29
> "Root=1-5ffb4c0f-103216757067a60b58ecf857" "api.dev.co"
> "arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:025080367422:certificate/0a6623b2-85e8-4d31-889e-9cc0354d74ec" 0 2021-01-10T18:48:47.921000Z "forward" "-" "LambdaUnhandled" "-" "-"
> "-" "-"

AFAICT, I'm sending the correct response, no?

---

Per my comment below, the fails on an endpoint that returns 'text/html'.  And endpoint that returns 'application/json' works; the following fails:

> {\n  statusCode: 200,\n  body: 'AAABAAEAIB4AA[...]//8=',\n
> multiValueHeaders: {\n    'x-powered-by': [ 'Express' ],\n
> 'access-control-allow-origin': [ '*' ],\n    'accept-ranges': [
> 'bytes' ],\n    'cache-control': [ 'public, max-age=0' ],\n
> 'last-modified': [ 'Sun, 10 Jan 2021 18:57:00 GMT' ],\n    etag: [
> 'W/"fb6-176eda8a060"' ],\n    'content-type': [ 'image/x-icon' ],\n
> 'content-length': [ 4022 ]\n  },\n  isBase64Encoded: true,\n
> statusDescription: '200 OK'\n}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.  Fixed.  Not sure where I was in the swirl when I posted this question but it came down to a bad HTTP header.  Actually, it looked to be a disallowed (not a bad) header.  I wound up tearing up serverless-express and simplifying it to the following:

https://gist.github.com/alsonkemp/cd133900bbc664095ee852cd20a5e9f5

Couldn't find any documentation about this...

I *think* it was the 'accept-ranges' header that borked it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the response supposed to be in JSON format? If that's the case you must double-quote all the attribute names, i.e. instead of...

```
{ statusCode: 200, body: 'Root...', ... }
```

it should be:

```json
{ "statusCode": 200, "body": "Root...", ... }
```

Comment: Ah.  Good point.  That's just the format provided by util.inspect (in Node) and captured by CloudWatch.  It's passed back out of the Lambda as a JS Obj.  The strange thing is that this is an endpoint that returns HTML and it doesn't work; an application/json does; a png get 'LambdaInvalidResponse'

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the case that the returned payload is > 1MB?
"The target is a Lambda function and the response body exceeds 1 MB." -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html